# How to install Visual Python in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, python

I am trying to do a Physics problem in python.  I need to install visual python because I get the error that it can't find the visual library when I type import visual from *

The documentation on the Visual Python site is totally useless.

I have gone into synaptic package manger and installed python-visual.  But I still get the same error.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Installing falls more into the realm of superuser.com and serverfault.com, you might try your question there. (Even though it is programming-related.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
from visual import *
```

instead of

```
import visual from *
```

If that doesn't work please post the literal error messages you get when trying to do so and the output of running

```
apt-cache policy python-visual
```

in a Terminal window.

Comment: I have:
from visual import *
I just made a typo when asking the question.

The output of the cmd you suggested is:
glen@glen-laptop:~$ apt-cache policy python-visual
python-visual:
  Installed: 1:5.12-1.1
  Candidate: 1:5.12-1.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:5.12-1.1 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
glen@glen-laptop:~$

Thanks,
Glen.

Comment: That looks good. What error do you get if you start python from a Terminal and type "from visual import *"?

Comment: Hmmm... this is strange.  It works when I run it in a cmd line.  I can even draw a sphere.  But when I run it from a file in IDLE I get the following error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/glen/Documents/Phys1101/Planet Orbit Simulation.py", line 1, in <module>
    from visual import *
ImportError: No module named visual

I suspect I have multiple versions of python or something???  Perhaps I have the vpython installed for the wrong one?  Any idea how I can point the one IDLE uses to the right vpython module?

Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Okay so I installed IDLE (using Python 2.6) and now it works.  I had previously installed Python 2.6 on ubuntu 9.10 and then when I found there was a bug I upgraded to 10.04.  I un installed Python 2.6 and installed Python 3.1.  I would prefer if I could get things working with the newest version of Python.  But it is working in the old version so it is not that important.  Thanks for your help.  I presume I need to set the Path variable for python to the right directory or make sure the python-visual package is in the python 3 folder.  Although I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score -2):

```
apt-get install python-visual
```

Comment: That's doesn't change anything after installing python-visual from Synaptics like Glen did.